# Adding subscripts in a pasted expression in ggplot2 axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Very briefly, in

```
xlab(expression(paste("Nitrate (",mu, g, "*", g^-1,")", sep="")))
```

i need to replace the "Nitrate" with Nmic where the string "mic" is subscripted:

```
expression(N[mic])
```

How can i combine both expressions?

Thank you!

Here is some plot to fiddle with:

```
    data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60),20,3)) 
    data$factor <- c(rep("f1", 4),rep("f2", 4), rep("f3", 4), rep("f4",4),rep("f5", 4))
    names(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "factor")
    melted <- melt(data)

    p <- ggplot(melted, aes(variable, value)) +
         geom_point(aes(col=factor)) +
xlab(expression(paste("Nitrate (",mu, g, "*", g^-1,")", sep="")))
```

Comment: is is what you want? xlab(expression(paste(N[mic]~"(",mu, g, "*", g^-1,")", sep="")))

Comment: Yes.Thank you very much.

Comment: @akrun, sorry, i messed up and wasnt aware i got an answer, when i figured it out.

Comment: @nouse Thanks for the reply.  It's okay.